# Highlight the in-between text in Android

Tags: android

I want to color the text between a " and ".
For example -

`<`body bgcolor=**"#000000"**`>` (I can't color them in the question, so I just made them bold)

I am using the following code but it is not working properly -

```
if (text.contains("\"")) {
                String syntaxText = "\"";
                SparseIntArray array = new SparseIntArray();
                int ofe = text.indexOf(syntaxText, 0);
                for (int ofs = 0; ofs < text.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
                    ofe = text.indexOf(syntaxText, ofs);
                    if (ofe == -1) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i=i+2) {
                        array.put(i, ofe);
                        }
                    }
                }
                int size = array.size();
                Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(et_note.getText());
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i=i++) {
                    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF00FF00), array.get(i), array.get(i+1), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    et_note.setText(WordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Although, I didn't expect the above code to work properly as I am a bit confused. 
Thanks for helping.

**EDIT -** 
`et_note` in my code is a EditText. The text will be given by then user and may have many **"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `startPos, endPos` is the postition of the two `"`. Try the following code:

```
            if (startPos != -1){
                Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(textValue);
                ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new int[] {}}, new int[] { Color.BLUE });
                TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, blueColor, null);

                spannable.setSpan(highlightSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                textView.setText(spannable);
            }
            else{
                textView.setText(textValue);
            }
```

Comment: How can I get endPos? et_note in my code is a edittext and it will have many "s.

Comment: You can try some methods such as `indexOf(String str), indexOf(String str, int fromIndex), lastIndexOf(String str),lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`...